# +layout.svelte.ts and +page.server.ts are executed twice after a FETCH is done. No cookies are avalilable in those instances. With sveltekit why?

Tags: cookies, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

Using the default Sveltekit ("version": "2.5.4") demo application I have the following on the **+page.server.ts**:

```js
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';
    
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({locals, url, cookies}) => {
    console.log("MAIN SERVER PAGE LOAD --> +page.server.ts: -- COOKIE VALUE: ", cookies.get('DEBUG'));
    return {
      query: {}
    };
};
```

For the **+layout.server.ts** I have the following:

```js
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals, cookies}) => {    
    console.log("LAYOUT SERVER LOAD --> +layout.server.ts -- ", cookies.get("DEBUG"));

    return {
      session: {}       
    };
};
```

I set a cookie on a different page for testing purposes:

```js
export const load = (({ cookies }) => {
    cookies.set('DEBUG', "This is for debugging", { 
        secure: false, 
        httpOnly: false, 
        path: '/' 
    });
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

On the main **+page.svelte** I have the following button:

```js
async function query(){
    let access_token = "SSSLOJGGTFGHKLNOKJVUBI";
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/v1/apples/get-apple/", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: null
    });
    console.log(await response.json());
}
```

I then do the following sequence:
Reload the main page which triggers the following logs:

> LAYOUT SERVER LOAD --> +layout.server.ts --  This is for debugging
> MAIN SERVER PAGE LOAD --> +page.server.ts: -- COOKIE VALUE:  This is for debugging

That is what I expect however after I then click the button that triggers the query function the following occurs:

> LAYOUT SERVER LOAD --> +layout.server.ts --  This is for debugging
> MAIN SERVER PAGE LOAD --> +page.server.ts: -- COOKIE VALUE:  This is for debugging
> LAYOUT SERVER LOAD --> +layout.server.ts --  undefined
> MAIN SERVER PAGE LOAD --> +page.server.ts: -- COOKIE VALUE:  undefined
> LAYOUT SERVER LOAD --> +layout.server.ts --  undefined
> MAIN SERVER PAGE LOAD --> +page.server.ts: -- COOKIE VALUE:  undefined

As you can see the +layout.server and +page.server are triggered twice and there are also no cookies available. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: [Do **not** screenshot text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), insert it as text and format it.

Comment: @brunnerh Thanks for the suggestion and the link for clarification. I've made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the cause of this issue is related to the VS-CODE extension "Console Ninja" - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.console-ninja.

It seems to do some kind of load on its side that mirrors clicks. Not sure of the specifics but this was the cause.